# Set Value of a TextArea inside a WebBrowser Control (C# / .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, html, webbrowser-control

I'm looking to set the value of a TextArea using the .NET WebBrowser Control.

I have been able to set the values of textboxes using the following code (replace "username" with the name of the texbox):

```
webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("username")[0].SetAttribute("Value", "SomeUser");
```

I tried using similar code on a TextArea (using GetElementById) and failed to remember that TextArea input types do not contain a "Value" attribute. I have also tried setting the InnerHtml and InnerText of the TextArea but the compiler continues to throw null reference exception errors or index out of bounds errors when trying set the value of the TextArea input.

Does anyone have any idea on how to set the text inside a TextArea using the WebBrowser Control?  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you had the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
   <textarea id='foo'>Testing</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

You can set the text in the `textarea` like this:

```
HtmlElement textArea = webBrowser1.Document.All["foo"];
if (textArea != null)
{
    textArea.InnerText = "This is a test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points just in case you haven't realised these:

- **GetElementById** will only return a single item or null, it is not a collection.
- **index out of bounds errors** will be thrown if you try and insert elements from one instance of the WebBrowser control into elements of another instance of the WebBrowser control.
- The **GetElementBy..** can be run straight from the **WebBrowser.Document** property so theres no need to access the **All[]** collection.