# Can't fill box with webbrowser

Tags: c#, vbulletin

This is the box I want to fill:

```xml
<textarea name="message" id="vB_Editor_001_textarea" rows="10" cols="60" style="display: block; width: 380px; height: 250px; " tabindex="1" dir="ltr"></textarea>
```

It's a PM box in a forum, it's the body to be specific, all the other fields are fill-able:

```
wb1.Document.GetElementById("recipients").SetAttribute("value", "HAHA");
wb1.Document.GetElementById("title").SetAttribute("value", "HAHA");
```

but I can't find a way to fill this one.

The forum is vBulletin.

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580052/set-value-of-a-textarea-inside-a-webbrowser-control-c-net and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642447/how-to-change-the-content-of-a-textarea-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the box is getting an auto-generated ID.  Try accessing it with the id you see from it (`vB_Editor_001_textarea`), otherwise, try finding it not by id but perhaps by name?

```
document.getElementByName()
```