# How do I fill a textbox in webkitbrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, webkit, browser

I have this code for a textbox on a website:

```
<textarea class="chat_input">

    Enter text for chat here

</textarea>
```

What I am trying to do, is to put text into it. On a different question, a person showed how to click a link that was a class with this code:

```
foreach (Node el in webKitBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
{
    if (((Element) el).GetAttribute("id") == "lnkId")
    {
        string urlString = ((Element) el).Attributes["href"].NodeValue;
        webKitBrowser1.Navigate(urlString);
    }
}
```

I tried adapting it for this code here:

```
message = txtMessage.Text;
foreach(Node txt in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea"))
{
    if(((Element)txt).GetAttribute("Class") == "chat_input")
    {
        ((Element)txt).SetAttribute("Value", message);
    }
}
```

When I debugged it, it went though the code 5 times, which is how many `textarea`'s there was. Does anyone know why it does not fill the `textbox`?

Comment: Already answered here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580052/set-value-of-a-textarea-inside-a-webbrowser-control-c-net

Comment: `.InnerText` is not available for `Node`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to not use `SetAttribute`, but set the `TextContent` property instead.

So:

```
if(((Element)txt).GetAttribute("Class") == "chat_input")
{
        ((Element)txt).TextContent = message;
}
```

Comment: `'WebKit.DOM.Element' does not contain a definition for 'InnerText' and no extension method 'InnerText' accepting a first argument of type 'WebKit.DOM.Element' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: Apologies, try TextContent.